# How do you create a SimpleDB on Amazon EC2?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, simpledb

Where exactly could I start creating a SimpleDB, I will be using PHP as the client. I can't find it anywhere on the AWS console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleDB is not in the AWS console yet, and it doesn't run anywhere on your EC2 instance.

The [JavaScript scratchpad](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-SimpleDB/1137) will allow you to experiment and learn about how SimpleDB works. You'll need to use the AWS SDK for PHP in your actual application to make the API calls to SimpleDB.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best place to start is here

Plenty of step by step images etc.

http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/simpledb/